# Laravel Login Issue

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

> (
>
> 1/1) ErrorException chmod(): Operation not permitted
>
> in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php (line 54) at
>   HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'chmod(): Operation not permitted',
>   '/var/www/html/laravel_app/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php',
>   54, array('dir' => '/var/www/html', 'dirPermissions' => 511,
>   'filePermissions' => 511, 'dp' => resource, 'file' => '.htaccess',
>   'fullPath' => '/var/www/html/.htaccess'))

I am getting this error on Laravel back-end, when I try to login, can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You have a brilliant username @Joe ;) lol

Comment: Actually website was working fine on godaddy server, I move all files from godaddy to AWS, Now almost all works fine, but when i try to login into back-end it gives me this error, Seems like some Permission Issue,Don't know.

Comment: @Joe *tips hat*